# React.js: Why is there no componentDidRender event?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, reactjs

I have just started using React, and a couple of times I have thought to myself: "Why is there no componentDidRender event?".

Say that I have a component that renders a table to the DOM, and I want to use [bootstrap-sortable](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable) on this table to allow the user to sort on whatever column he wants. In the case of bootstrap-sortable you need to run `$.boostrapSortable()` after the table is drawn, in order to initialize the plugin.

As I see it, there are two handlers on a React component that would be logical to consider to use for this purpose:

- `componentDidMount`: This does not work because the DOM does not seem to be updated at this point of the execution.
- `componentDidUpdate`: This could possibly work, but it does not fire on the initial render.

I am not saying that React is actually missing a componentDidRender function, because I assume that there is a perfectly logical explanation as to why it is not there. I am just asking if someone could explain why such a function is not present, and what would be the "React way" to handle a case like the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `componentDidMount` you can do: `this.getDOMNode()` to get a reference to the underlying DOM for that component. So if you do want to use your mounted component with jQuery you can do:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $(this.getDOMNode());
}
```

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html

Here's a fiddle which shows jQuery acting on the DOM node of a react component:

http://jsfiddle.net/sa5e88ys/1/

As you can see, it adds a border to the div as expected. If you're still having problems I guess it could be with the plugin you're using rather than jQuery or react?

Comment: Yes, this is all good, but it still seems like componentDidMount is too early in the life cycle for the plugin to work. I tested putting $.bootstrapSortable() inside a timeout clause of 100 ms, and then it worked. Without the timeout it did not work.

Comment: You are right, it does seem to be at the correct time of the life cycle. I guess bootstrap-sortable may contain the problem, then.

Comment: componentDidMount is called after mounting the component. After mount, render starts so not sure how much getDOMNode can provide stable outcome here.

Answer (score 4):

Although there's no `componentDidRender`, you can make a method with the desired behavior and call it in both `componentDidMount` (which is only called after the first render) and `componentDidUpdate` (which is called after every render but the first).

Also, this is the preferred way of getting a ref to a DOM node from within the component:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: componentDidMount is actually called after first mount not render. componentDidUpdate is called after the state is updated, not after re-render.
Rendered means entire dom painiting is completed. Right now, we don't have access to any lifecycle method to run a side-effect after render.